# Rebinding navigation keys when using isearch

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, minibuffer, isearch

I've rebound most of my navigation keys using `bind-keys*` and am trying to create a uniform layout. But I have the problem that when I trigger isearch, point is not actually placed in the minibuffer but remains in the main buffer, so that, when I trigger a navigation command, such as `backward-char`, the search ends and point moves back in the main buffer. Meanwhile, if I tap `<right>` after starting isearch, it automatically places point into the minibuffer. However, it seems `<right>` is not bound to a special command as far as I can tell, `embark-bindings` doesn't return any binding for it. How can I get some other key sequence to imitate the behavior of  so I can use it to navigate my isearch-input?

Emacs version is 30.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.38, cairo version 1.18.0) of 2023-10-10

Comment: Yes, isearch doesn't use the minibuffer at all.  I don't know what you have `<right>` bound to, but that's not standard behaviour (I don't know what `embark-bindings` is either, though).  I don't really understand the question, but use `M-x describe-keymap RET isearch-mode-map` or just `C-s C-h b` to see the isearch bindings.  You can bind things in that keymap yourself, which I'm imagining is the answer to your question.

Comment: @philis If I trigger isearch and press `right`, point ends up in the minibuffer, and there apparently is an `minibuffer-local-isearch-map` described as "Keymap for editing Isearch strings in the minibuffer.". Getting there is exactly what I mean.

Comment: `M-e` is the standard key binding for doing that.

Comment: @phils Thanks, but how do I test whether an isearch is happening in a function? I tried `(bound-and-true-p isearch-mode)`, but it didn't hold, and I tried finding out whether some other mode was holding, but I didn't find any, and I also tried `(bound-and-true-p isearch-forward)`, but that one triggered always, whether I was doing a search or not.

Comment: State your Emacs version, please. Recent versions do, I think, make Isearch use the minibuffer. (Dunno whether that is in any way related to your problem, even it's true.)

Comment: @Drew GNU Emacs 30.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.38, cairo version 1.18.0)
 of 2023-10-10

Comment: `isearch-mode` (which is always `boundp` so you can safely eval it directly) is true while isearch is active.  You'll need to describe in detail the circumstances in which "it didn't hold", because if it's not true then the isearch has ended.

Comment: @phils I wrote a function `ahpbwd` with `(cond (((bound-and-true-p isearch-mode) (isearch-edit-string))) (t (backward-char))))` as a condition and bound it to C-a, but when I trigger `isearch-forward` and press C-a, it moves point in the main document and breaks off the search.

Comment: In case you simply mean `isearch-mode` is nil when you're editing a search string in the minibuffer via `isearch-edit-string` then that's expected -- you're *not* isearching at that point in time; you're editing text in the minibuffer (if you were isearching you wouldn't be *able* to edit the text by typing, after all).

Comment: Your code has too many parens and would signal an error.  Without that error your code works -- but again, `isearch-mode` is *guaranteed* to be bound, so all you need is `(cond (isearch-mode (isearch-edit-string)) (t (backward-char)))`.  Which also works for me.  But per previous comments, if you want an `isearch-mode` binding, use `isearch-mode-map`.  Having a command which is explicitly testing that state to choose what to do seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @phils The misbracketing is an artifact of me simplifying the code because it had more clauses. But I just bracketed everything else out and only tried the condition as you wrote it. Just `(defun ahpbwd ()
  (interactive)
  (cond
        (isearch-mode
         (isearch-edit-string))
        (t (backward-char))
      )).` It still doesn't work for me. Could it be a bug? As to why I'm defining a special function, `bind-key*` overlays its keymap over all others, so if one wants mode-specific behavior, one has to define it through functions. Also, that's not the only thing the function does.

Comment: I see that you're testing in 30.0.50 which is unstable, so please start by re-testing in a stable release.  It's very difficult for anyone else to say anything with certainty about some arbitrary unstable version of Emacs you happen to have compiled.  (And if you're not confident about debugging Emacs, I would strongly urge you to *not* run an unstable version at all.)

Comment: Put your version/platform info in the question, not just in a comment. Questions need to stand on their own. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable. Thx.

Comment: You never said which key sequence you're trying to use, but you did indicate you're *not* binding it in `isearch-mode-map`, so... are you trying to use a key sequence which *has an existing binding in `isearch-mode-map`*?  If so, that is not going to work unless you unbind the latter, because isearch's own bindings take precedence when isearching.  You can use `C-h k` and `C-h b` while isearching to inspect the bindings.  (And if that's what's happening then I would again suggest that you are complicating things for yourself by not binding an isearch-specific command in the isearch keymap.)

Comment: If that doesn't explain it, your question is lacking in detail and you need to add example code which reproduces the issue so that you're not asking people to guess what you're doing.